# Docker parallel operations limit

Tags: docker, concurrency, dockerfile, docker-registry

Is there a limit to the number of parallel Docker push/pulls you can do?

> E.g. if you thread Docker pull / push commands such that they are
>   pulling/pushing different images at the same time what would be the
>   upper limit to the number of parallel push/pulls

Or alternatively

> On one terminal you do docker pull ubuntu on another you do docker
>   pull httpd etc - what would be the limit Docker would support?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The options are set in the configuration file (Linux-based OS it is located in the path: /etc/docker/daemon.json and C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json on Windows)

Open /etc/docker/daemon.json (If doesn't exist, create it)

Add the values(for push/pulls) and set parallel operations limit

```
{
    "max-concurrent-uploads": 1,
    "max-concurrent-downloads": 1
}
```

Restart daemon: `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, this was much easier to follow.

Comment: Good to know. I answered because the accepted one was too long 

Comment: for Docker Desktop on mac, you need to go to `Preferences | Docker Engine` and specify the config there

Comment: "(If doesn't exist, create it)" Hint: if it doesn't exist, it's most likely your current user doesn't have permission to /etc/docker instead of the file not existent. This assumption is dangerous because you may accidentally overwrite the default config.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/
"Edit the daemon.json file, which is usually located in /etc/docker/. You may need to create this file, if it does not yet exist." 

Answer (score 28):

The docker daemon (dockerd) has two flags:

```
  --max-concurrent-downloads int          Set the max concurrent downloads for each pull
                                          (default 3)
  --max-concurrent-uploads int            Set the max concurrent uploads for each push
                                          (default 5)
```

The upper limit will likely depend on the number of open files you permit for the process (`ulimit -n`). There will be some overhead of other docker file handles, and I expect that each push and pull opens multiple handles, one for the remote connection, and another for the local file storage.

To compound the complication of this, each push and pull of an image will open multiple connections, one per layer, up to the concurrent limit. So if you run a dozen concurrent pulls, you may have 50-100 potential layers to pull.

While docker does allow these limits to be increased, there's a practical limit where you'll see diminishing returns if not a negative return to opening more concurrent connections. Assuming the bandwidth to the remote registry is limited, more connections will simply split that bandwidth, and docker itself will wait until the very first layer finishes before it starts unpacking that transmission. Also any aborted docker pull or push will lose any partial transmissions of a layer, so you increase the potential data you'd need to retransmit with more concurrent connections.

The default limits are well suited for a development environment, and if you find the need to adjust them, I'd recommend measuring the performance improvement before trying to find the max number of concurrent sessions.

Comment: Thanks - this is so helpful. That being said though if you had to test a Docker Registry endpoint to see how well it scales and how many concurrent connections it can support or in general how well it performs under stress - would it then be wise to fiddle around with these parameters and hit the Docker Registry from multiple endpoints?  Grateful if you could shed some light on this topic too.

Comment: If you control both the registry, the network, and the endpoints, this could be optimized. But I fear the return on the effort will be small, unless your use case is unusual. Most would see much more benefit to optimizing the images themselves.

Comment: For Windows user, this can be done by creating a `daemon.json` file in `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#on-windows

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Docker for Windows and WSL2:
You can (and should) set the options on the Settings tab:

[Docker for Windows Docker Engine settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S52iG.png)